# Why can't revoke in spl_token be signed by the delegate account

Tags: spl-token

Revoke instruction in spl_token has a check for the owner to be a signer which in the case of a delegated account seems unnecessary. Does anyone know why it's there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`revoke` removes a delegate from your token account that you have previously approved using `approve`.  If there is no signer check for the owner on `revoke`, then anyone can revoke your delegation, which would make approvals nearly useless.  People could run spam bots that just go around removing delegations, likely breaking other apps in the process.

Comment: My bad should've been more clear, I don't want anyone to sign it, I was wondering if the delegate account can be the signer and revoke its own authority

Comment: Ah, this is supported in token-2022, but not in the normal token program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/2872

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revoke yourself from a token as the delegate you can transfer to a PDA token account (removes delegate) then transfer back to the original account so the balance is unchanged